# How do i avoid the redundant "maven-update" in eclipse if i have 2 maven projects while one needs the other as a library

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have two java-projects configured with maven. One is a lib to the other. I always have to do maven install, maven update that my main projects gets the updated lib, when i change something.

Is there a way to avoid the annoying maven install / maven update procedure (in other words to automate this process)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [M2Eclipse](http://www.sonatype.org/m2eclipse) plugin for Eclipse, which provides dependency management within Eclipse. If you have both projects open, it will automatically refer to the other project, without the need for `mvn install`. Any changes you make in one project will immediately be visible in the other - as long as your POM refers to the current version of the other project (usually SNAPSHOT).

Answer (score 0):

If you develop them at the same time, It's probable that they shoudl be two modules of one project. If you set up them that way eclipse can manage their dependecy withou installing the lib into the repository.